How to enable "Tag Parser" mode for IntelliSense in Visual Studio
In Visual Studio Code, you can configure the IntelliSense engine to use "Tag Parser" mode for faster performance, as shown in the image.

Is there a way to enable a similar mode in Visual Studio? This setting significantly improves the speed of IntelliSense.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3416

Looks like tag parser is typically enabled by default for C++ projects in Visual Studio 2022.

In Visual Studio 2022, the tag parser is typically enabled by default for C++ projects. Looks like tag parser is part of the IntelliSense feature.
The tag parser is a “fuzzy” C++ parser used for browsing and navigation. It is designed to be very fast but does not attempt to fully comprehend every code construct.
If you encounter more issues about tag parser, please read doc: Tag parser issues
